# Zend Form: use the result of a field entered by the user in another field

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-framework3

I want to use a field that the user entered in a form, in another field using a regular function:

I want to use the result of `function addAppId()` in the Regex of the other field `addDbName()`

So I want to know if it is possible to save the result of the first function in a variable and use it in the second function (of my form).

```
protected function addAppId()
{
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'app_id',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'App Name',
            'label_size' => 4,
            'elm_size' => 8,
            'empty_option' => __('---Selectionner une Application---'),
            'value_options' => array()
        ),
        'input_filter' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                new \Zend\Filter\StripTags(),
                new \Zend\Filter\StringTrim(),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                new \Zend\Validator\GreaterThan(array(
                    'min' => 0,
                )),
                new \Zend\I18n\Validator\IsInt(),
            ),
        ),
    ));
}

protected function addDbName()
    {

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'db_name',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Database Name',               
            ),
.............

                    new \Zend\Validator\Regex(array(
                        'pattern'=> '/^[I_WANT_TO_ADD_THE_VARIABLE_HERE]/',

            ),
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you want to validate the field `db_name`, using a regex expression, which have to containt the `app_id` value.

If so, the answer is to use the `Callback` validator.
This is an exemple:

```php
/**
 * This must be populated in the constructor or in the init function,
 * however before calling addAppId()
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appId = array(
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'Wordpress',
        'dbPrefix' => 'wp'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'name' => 'Magento',
        'prefix' => 'magento'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'name' => 'My wonderful app',
        'prefix' => 'my_wonderful_app'
    )
);

protected function addAppId() {
    $valueOptions = [];
    foreach($this->appId as $appId => $app){
        $valueOptions[$appId] = $app['name'];
    }
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'app_id',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'App Name',
            'value_options' => $valueOptions
        )
    ));

}

protected function addDbName() {
    $prefixes = [];
    foreach($this->appId as $appId => $app){
        $prefixes[$appId] = $app['prefix'];
    }
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'db_name',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Database Name',
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Callback',
                'options' => [
                    'callback' => function($value, $context) use ($prefixes) {
                        if(!isset($context['app_id'])){
                            return false;
                        }
                        $appId = $context['app_id'];
                        if(!isset($prefixes[$appId])){
                            return false;
                        }

                        // If you want to check that the app_id name is the
                        // prefix of the db, pattern should be:
                        // $pattern = '/^'.$appId.'.*/';
                        $pattern = '/^' . $prefixes[$appId] . '/';

                        $status = preg_match($pattern, $value);
                        return $status !== '' && $status === false;
                    },
                    'messages' => [
                        \Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE => "Database name doesn't match the App name"
                    ]
                ]
            )
        )
    ));
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ermenegildo, but it still not working, i copied your code of addDbName and

i have the message : "Database name doesn't match the App name"

PS: the first field (app id)  is a select field not a Text

Comment: Missed it, sorry. If you edit your question showing how you populate your select options, I'll update the answer ;)

Comment: if you have time please update your answer ^^ and thank u very much :D

Comment: I wanted to see how you filled the array, not how you set it to the form element :P I'll make an exemple, but it won't obviously work as "copy&paste"..

Comment: Could I see the data array you pass to `value_options`? Otherwise it is quite impossible to give you a good solution, since there are a plenty of different possibilities..

Comment: Join this chatroom: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192962/zend-form-use-the-result-of-a-field-entered-by-the-user-in-another-field

Comment: wich array ?? :p

Comment: they told me : You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq. urgh, i have only 11
can we talk by mail ? wassim.remmas@orange.com

Comment: For element 'app_id`, you are setting value options this way: `'value_options' => array()`. So, reading this, you are creating a select with no option. Somehow, somewhere, you are populating your select.. I'd like to see that part

Comment: so in the controller i have : 
**$appList = $this->db->getApps();
$searchForm->get('app_id')->setValueOptions($appList);**

       and the function that retrieves the data from the database

**public function getApps()
 {
  $data = array ();
  $queryBuilder = $this->db->createQueryBuilder ();
  $statement = $queryBuilder->select ( 'aps.id', 'aps.name' )->from ( 'apps', 'aps' )
  ->execute ();
  foreach ( $statement as $row ) {
   $data [$row ['id']] = $row ['name'];
  }
  return array (
    '' => '---Select App Name---' 
  ) + $data;
 }**

Comment: You shouldn't set the options from the controller, but in the form itself.
You should retrieve the form from a factory, which automatically creates the form with all its dependencies. Inside it, you can populate the select with your options (or, even better, you use a custom select)

Comment: Can u do it for me please ?I am a trainee, this application is already realized, I do not quite understand their code, and i never used Zend framework :(

Comment: Check this guide: https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Collecting_User_Input_with_Forms.html

Chapters 7, 8 and 9.

Comment: Updated the answer with a hint of how it should be done